# Project Euler 50, what's wrong with my loop?

Tags: r, algorithm, loops

[Project Euler #50](http://projecteuler.net/problem=50)

> The prime 41, can be written as the sum of six consecutive primes:
>
> 41 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13
>
> This is the longest sum of consecutive primes that adds to a prime below one-hundred.
>
> The longest sum of consecutive primes below one-thousand that adds to a prime, contains 21 terms, and is equal to 953.
>
> Which prime, below one-million, can be written as the sum of the most consecutive primes?

Here is my code:

```
SieveOfE <- function(n) {
    primes <- rep(TRUE, n)
    primes[1] <- FALSE
    last.prime <- 2
    while (last.prime <= sqrt(n)) {
        primes[seq.int(2*last.prime, n, last.prime)] <- FALSE
        last.prime <- last.prime + min(which(primes[(last.prime + 1) : n]))
    }
    which(primes)
}

primes <- SieveOfE(3940)
primes <- as.numeric(primes)

ans <- 0
length <- 0

for (i in 1:length(primes)) {
    for (j in length(primes):i) {
        if ((sum(primes[i:j]) %in% primes) && (j - i > length)) {
            length <- j - i
            ans <- sum(primes[i:j])
        }
    }
}

ans
```

I keep getting the answer to be 3821 even though I know it is in the 900000+ range.

Comment: Why are you generating the primes only up to 3940?

Comment: The sum of the consecutive primes must be less than one million.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm not too familiar with R, but shouldn't your inner loop be `j in i + 1:length(primes)`?

Comment: The sum must also be a prime and you don't know about any primes greater than 3940. You need to sieve up to `1e6` to be able to tell if the sums are prime.

Comment: Ah, simple mistake. I still am off though - but a lot closer.